# Find longest sequence of 0's in the integer list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

`A = [1,2,0,0,3,4,5,-1,0,2,-1,-3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2,-3,-4,-5,0,0,0]`

Return initial and ending index of longest sequence of `0`'s in the list.
As, longest sequence of `0`'s in above list is `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` so it should return `12,19` as starting and ending index.Please help with some one line python code.

I tried :

```
k = max(len(list(y)) for (c,y) in itertools.groupby(A) if c==0)
print(k)
```

which return `8` as the max length.

Now, how to find start and end index of longest sequence?

Comment: So, you have an approach, presumably some code, and possibly some result of running that code. What is your question?

Comment: I need to write this in one line python code

Comment: That's not a question, that's an assignment.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please check my code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can first use `enumerate` to zip the item with index,

and then `itertools.groupby(list,operator.itemgetter(1))` to group by item,

filter only `0`s using `list(y) for (x,y) in list if x == 0`,

and at last `max(list, key=len)` to get the longest sequence.

```
import itertools,operator
r = max((list(y) for (x,y) in itertools.groupby((enumerate(A)),operator.itemgetter(1)) if x == 0), key=len)
print(r[0][0]) # prints 12
print(r[-1][0]) # prints 19
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
 A = [1,2,0,0,3,4,5,-1,0,2,-1,-3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,-3,-4,-5,0,0,0]

count = 0
prev = 0
indexend = 0
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    if A[i] == 0:
        count += 1
    else:            
      if count > prev:
        prev = count
        indexend = i
      count = 0

print("The longest sequence of 0's is "+str(prev))
print("index start at: "+ str(indexend-prev))
print("index ends at: "+ str(indexend-1))
```

Output:

> The longest sequence of 0's ist 8
>
> ```
> index start at: 12
>
> index ends at: 19
> ```

Comment: Your solution will fail if the longest sequence includes the last item in the list. This could of course easily be solved by adding a final (if count > prev ....) directly after the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

A nice concise native python approach

```
target = 0
A = [1,2,0,0,3,4,5,-1,0,2,-1,-3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,-3,-4,-5,0,0,0]

def longest_seq(A, target):
    """ input list of elements, and target element, return longest sequence of target """
    cnt, max_val = 0, 0 # running count, and max count
    for e in A: 
        cnt = cnt + 1 if e == target else 0  # add to or reset running count
        max_val = max(cnt, max_val) # update max count
    return max_val
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have the length, find that k-length sequence of 0's in the original list.  Expanding the stuff you'll eventually work into one line:

```
# k is given in your post
k_zeros = [0]*k
for i in range(len(A)-k):
    if A[i:i+k] == k_zeros:
        break
# i is the start index; i+k-1 is the end
```

Can you wrap this into a single statement now?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as one long disgusting line!

```
"-".join([sorted([list(y) for c,y in itertools.groupby([str(v)+"_"+str(i) for i,v in enumerate(A)], lambda x: x.split("_")[0]) if c[0] == '0'],key=len)[-1][a].split("_")[1] for a in [0,-1]])
```

It keeps track of indices by turning `[1,2,0...]` into `["1_0","2_1","0_2",..]` and then doing some splitting and parsing.

Yes it's very ugly and you should go with one of the other answers but I wanted to share

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1,2,0,0,3,4,5,-1,0,2,-1,-3,0,0,0,2,-3,-4,-5,0,0,0,0]

count = 0
prev = 0
indexend = 0
indexcount = 0
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    if A[i] == 0:
       count += 1
       indexcount = i
    else:            
       if count > prev:
       prev = count
       indexend = i
       count = 0

if count > prev:
   prev = count
   indexend = indexcount

print("The longest sequence of 0's is "+str(prev))
print("index start at: "+ str(indexend-prev))
print("index ends at: "+ str(indexend-1))
```

To also consider if longest 0's sequecnces are at the end.

**Output**

```
 The longest sequence of 0's is 4
 index start at: 18
 index ends at: 21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This solution i submitted in Codility with 100 percent efficieny.
    class Solution {
        public int solution(int N) {
            int i = 0;
                int gap = 0;
                `bool startZeroCount = false;
                List<int> binaryArray = new List<int>();
                while (N > 0)
                {
                    binaryArray.Add(N % 2);
                    N = N / 2;
                    i++;
                }
                
                List<int> gapArr = new List<int>();
                for (int j = i-1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    if (binaryArray[j] == 1)
                    {
                        if(startZeroCount)
                        {
                            gapArr.Add(gap);
                            gap = 0;
                           
                        }
                        startZeroCount = true;
                    }
                    else if(binaryArray[j] == 0)
                    {
                        if (startZeroCount)
                            gap++;
                    }                
                }
                gapArr.Sort();            
                if (gapArr.Count != 0)
                    return gapArr[gapArr.Count - 1];
                else return 0;enter code here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to completely avoid Python iteration you can do it with Numpy. E.g., for very long sequences, using for loops may be relatively slow. This method will use pre-compiled C for-loops under the hood. The disadvantage is that you have multiple for-loops here. Nonetheless, overall, below algorithm should be a speed gain on longer sequences.

```
import numpy as np
def longest_sequence(bool_array):
    where_not_true = np.where(~bool_array)[0]
    lengths_plus_1 = np.diff(np.hstack((-1,where_not_true,len(bool_array))))
    index          = np.cumsum(np.hstack((0,lengths_plus_1)))
    start_in_lngth = np.argmax(lengths_plus_1)
    start          = index[         start_in_lngth]
    length         = lengths_plus_1[start_in_lngth] - 1
    return start, length

t = np.array((0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1))
print(longest_sequence(t==0))
print(longest_sequence(t==1))
p = np.array((0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1))
print(longest_sequence(p==0))
print(longest_sequence(p==1))
```