# Find the position of the longest repeated letter

Tags: python, string, search

I have a file that contains letters. I need to find the position of the longest repeated letters. For example, if the file contains `aaassdddffccsdddfgssfrsfspppppppppppddsfs`, I need a program that finds the position of `ppppppppppp`. I know that I need to use a `.index` function to find the location however I am stuck on the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find longest sequence of 0's in the integer list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166522/find-longest-sequence-of-0s-in-the-integer-list) (Simply convert your string to a list.)

Comment: You should post a [mcve] that shows us what you've tried, otherwise people will think you want us to do your homework for you. ;)

Comment: Perfect duplicate of this. Probably is homework. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664150/counting-longest-occurence-of-repeated-sequence-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting longest occurence of repeated sequence in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664150/counting-longest-occurence-of-repeated-sequence-in-python)

Comment: Also, there might be a chance of a tie.

Comment: [Counting longest occurence of repeated sequence in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664150/counting-longest-occurence-of-repeated-sequence-in-python) finds the length of the longest repeating sequence, but it doesn't show how to find the _position_ of that sequence.

Comment: I think you want to find the starting position of the longest repeating sequence, that is the repeating letters have to be next to each other. Eg, in "aaaabbbcbbb" you want to find the position of the a's, not the b's, even though there are more b's in total. You should make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

mystr = 'aaassdddffccsdddfgssfrsfspppppppppppddsfs'

idx = 0
maxidx, maxlen = 0, 0
for _, group in itertools.groupby(mystr):
    grouplen = sum(1 for _ in group)
    if grouplen > maxlen:
        maxidx, maxlen = idx, grouplen
    idx += grouplen
```

Gives the idx and the length of the longest identical substring:

```
>>> print(maxidx, maxlen)
25, 11

>>> mystr[25:25+11]
'ppppppppppp'
```

Comment: That's definitely a lot more readable than `max(((next(g)[0],sum(1 for _ in g))for _,g in groupby(enumerate(mystr),key=itemgetter(1))),key=itemgetter(1))[0]` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to loop through the entire string.  Keep track of each new letter you come across as well as it's index and how long each sequence is.  Only store the max sequence

```
s = 'aaassdddffccsdddfgssfrsfspppppppppppddsfs'

max_c = max_i = max_len = None
cur_c = cur_i = cur_len = None
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c != cur_c:
        if max_len is None or cur_len > max_len:
            max_c, max_i, max_len = cur_c, cur_i, cur_len
        cur_c = c
        cur_i = i
        cur_len = 1
    else:
        cur_len += 1
else:
    # One last check when the loop completes
    if max_len is None or cur_len > max_len:
        max_c, max_i, max_len = cur_c, cur_i, cur_len

print max_c, max_i, max_len
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an oneliner

```
from itertools import groupby
from functools import reduce
[(k, next(g)[0], sum(1 for _ in g)+1) for k, g in groupby(enumerate(
    'aaassdddffccsdddfgssfrsfspppppppppppddsfs'), key=itemgetter(1))]
```

The above generates (key, position, length). You can get the maximum length by
applying reduce

```
from itertools import groupby
from functools import reduce
from operator import itemgetter
reduce(lambda x,y:x if x[2] >= y[2] else y,
   ((k, next(g)[0], sum(1 for _ in g)+1) for k, g in groupby(enumerate(
    'aaassdddffccsdddfgssfrsfspppppppppppddsfs'), key=itemgetter(1))))
```

Comment: you can use max with key = itemgetter(2) instead of reduce

Answer (score 0):

A quick way of achieving this is to use a regex to match repeating characters with `(.)(\1+)`.  Then we loop over all those results using a generator comprehension and find the `max` according to the length (`key=len`).  Finally having found the largest string, we call `thestr.index()` to find where the longest repeated letter occurred:

```
import re
txt = "aaassdddffccsdddfgssfrsfspppppppppppddsfs"
idx = txt.index(max((''.join(f) for f in re.findall(r"(.)(\1+)", txt)), key=len))
print(idx)
```

Here is the same code broken out into stages:

```
>>> import re
>>> txt = "aaassdddffccsdddfgssfrsfspppppppppppddsfs"
>>> matches = list(''.join(f) for f in re.findall(r"(.)(\1+)", txt))
>>> print(matches)
['aaa', 'ss', 'ddd', 'ff', 'cc', 'ddd', 'ss', 'ppppppppppp', 'dd']
>>> longest = max(matches, key=len)
>>> print(longest)
ppppppppppp
>>> print(txt.index(longest))
25
```