# Find all subsequences in list

Tags: python, list, sequence

I have a list of 1s and 0s as follows:

```py
lst = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

I'm looking for a method that finds *all* the sequences of 0s within this list and returns their indices, i.e.:

```py
[1, 3]
[8, 9]
[13, 13]
[15, 16]
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166522/find-longest-sequence-of-0s-in-the-integer-list) shows a method of getting the longest sequence, but I can't think of a way to work from it to get all the sequences.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Recommendation: Change your `list` variable to something else, as its currently overwriting the builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 3.8 you can modify the first answer in referenced code by using the [Walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)

**Code**

```
from itertools import groupby
import operator

lst = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

r = [(p[1][0][0], p[1][-1][0]) for (x,y) in groupby(enumerate(lst), operator.itemgetter(1)) if (p := (x, list(y)))[0] == 0]
print(r)
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 3), (8, 9), (13, 13), (15, 16)]
```

**Explanation**

Adding a Walrus operator to OP code reference we have:

```
r = [p for (x,y) in groupby(enumerate(lst), operator.itemgetter(1)) if (p := (x, list(y)))[0] == 0]
# Outputs: [(0, [(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)]), (0, [(8, 0), (9, 0)]), (0, [(13, 0)]), (0, [(15, 0), (16, 0)])]
```

Conditional in the list comprehension:

```
(p := (x, list(y)))[0] # is a check for x == 0
```

Need to capture the right terms in p

First p[1] for instance is:

```
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)]
```

We want the (1, 3) which index 0 of the first and last term of the list

```
p[1][0][0]   # index zero of first tuple -> 1
p[1][-1][0]  # index zero of last tuple  -> 3
```

So in general we have the tuple:

```
(p[1][0][0], p[1][-1][0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(l):
    _1to0 = [ i+1 for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(l[:-1], l[1:])) if y == 0 and x != y ]
    _0to1 = [ i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(l[:-1], l[1:])) if x == 0 and x != y ]
    if l[0] == 0:
      _1to0.insert(0,0)
    if l[-1] == 0:
      _0to1.append(len(l))
    return zip(_1to0, _0to1)
```

1. Detect changes 1 -> 0 (starts) and 0 -> 1 (ends)
2. If start with 0, add a start at indice 0
3. If ends with 0, add an end at the last indice
4. Combine starts and ends in pairs

```
    In [1]: list(f([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]))
    Out[1]: [(1, 3), (8, 9), (13, 13), (15, 16)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

indexes_counts = []
start_zero_index = -1
is_inside_zero_sequence = False
zero_length = 0
# Use enumerate to loop on the lists and indexes
for i, x in enumerate(list):
    # If inside a zeroes sequence
    if is_inside_zero_sequence:
        # If current item is zero too
        if 0 == x:
            # Increase the zro_length counter
            zero_length += 1
        # Else, current element is not zero
        else:             
            # Handle end of zeroes sequence
            indexes_counts.append([start_zero_index, zero_length])
            is_inside_zero_sequence = False
            zero_length = 0
    # If not in zeroes sequence and current number is not zero
    elif 0 == x:
            # Handle not zero
            is_inside_zero_sequence = True
            start_zero_index = i
            zero_length = 1

# [[1, 3], [8, 2], [13, 1], [15, 2]]
print(indexes_counts)
```